# Como criar um simulador usando SESSION

Tags: php, html, mysql

Olá, estou tentando criar um simulador usando SESSION, mas como sou iniciante e muito leigo ainda, estou pedindo a ajuda dos amigos.
Seguinte criei a pagina onde o usuário poderá alterar o logotipo, simples ele seleciona a imagem e altera junto ao BD, que por sua vez envia a nova imagem para o endereço do Site na posição da Logo-Marca do usuário.

Mas eu gostaria de dar a oportunidade do usuário simular algumas alterações, mas ao sair do navegador as alterações efetuadas por ele se desfizesse, voltando ao original.

Pergunto aos amigos tem como? E se tem como devo proceder?

Abaixo relaciono o arquivo que crie para alterar o logotipo, e o arquivo desse logotipo vindo do BD.

Aquivo que altera o logotipo:

```
<?php

include 'cabecalho.php';

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
$logo = $_POST['logo'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho") or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" />

<div align="center"  style="margin: 0 0 0 180px; max-width:1000px;">
<div align="left" style="margin:0 0 0 10px;"><h3>Configure o Logo de Seu Site</h3></div>

<div align="left" style=" border-right:solid 2px; padding:10px; float:left; width:300px; height:auto; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">

<label>Logo: </label><br />
<label>Nome do arquivo: <span><?php echo $res['logo'];?></span><br />
<label>Imagem do arquivo: </label><br />
<img width="100" height="auto" src="../upload/<?php echo $res['logo'];?>" title="Logo Marca"/>
<br />
</div>

<div style="padding:10px; float:left; width:655px; height:auto; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">
<br /><br />

<div align="center" style=" padding:2px; float:left; width:190px; height:auto; float:left;">
<label>Configure o Logo:</label><br />
<a href="edit_logo-upd.php?codigo=<?php echo $res['codigo'];?>">
<img style="padding:15px;" width="30" height="auto" src="img/edit.png" title="Atualizar Imagem do Logo" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Arquivo que recebe do BD o logotipo:

```
    <li><a href="index.php">
    <img width="150" height="auto" src="upload/
    <?php
    include "../conexao.php";
    $logo = $_POST['logo'];
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho");
    $res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    echo $res['logo'];
    ?>
    " title="Home"/></a>
    </li>
```

Se os amigos puderem me dar uma luz de como posso criar esse simulador, ficarei muito agradecido.

Abraços à todos.

Comment: Não seria ideal utilizar Javascript? É possível fazer um coisa bem 'legal', irei tentar responder mais tarde. ;]

Comment: Fico no aguardo!

Comment: Não esqueci de você. ;]

Comment: Pode colocar o código que pega o POST/GET do formulário, apenas para ver como está declarado as variáveis? Isso é, o código que faz o `INSERT` na imagem.

Answer (score 2):

O seu objetivo é simular a alteração do logo, correto?
Por isso irei utilizar o Javascript para

Este será o item alterado:

```
<img width="150" height="auto" src="upload/<? echo $nomeLogo ?>" title="Home"/>
```

Minha intenção é permitir o usuário alterar este logo, por isso irei adicionar um ícone de lápis ao canto da imagem e permitir a alteração, via Javascript.

Afinal, porque processar no lado do servidor?

### Simulador no lado do cliente:

> **Teste isso clicando no link abaixo:**

```js
document.getElementById("alterarLogo").addEventListener("change", function() {
       document.getElementById('logo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
       document.getElementById("salvar").style.display = "block";
});
```

```css
html {
  background-color: #555;
}
/* Isso é apenas para demonstração, mas pode servir como base em seu projeto!  */

.logo {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.alterar {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.salvar {
  float: left;
  line-height: 21px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* Isso é necessário para ocultar o input, altere para ver o que irá mudar :P  */

#alterarLogo,
#salvarLogo {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://goo.gl/XGflc6" width="150" id="logo" class="logo" alt="logo">

<form action="edit_logo-upd.php" method="post">

  <label for="alterarLogo">
    <img src="https://goo.gl/Kmg0EB" width="20" height="20" class="alterar" alt="Alterar">
  </label>
  
  <label for="salvarLogo">
    <span class="salvar" id="salvar"> Salvar </span> 
  </label>

  <input name="logo" id="alterarLogo" type="file">
  <input name="salvar" id="salvarLogo" type="submit">

</form>
```

Se preferir, [clique aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/f600ox9s/).

**Construção:**

> HTML/PHP:

```
<?php
include "../conexao.php";
//$logo = $_POST['logo']; não vi utilização desta variável.
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pagcabecalho");
$res = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$logoResultado = $res['logo'];
?>
<img src="upload/<?= $logoResultado ?>" width="150" id="logo" class="logo" alt="logo">
```

Isso irá exibir a imagem normalmente, como em seu  código.

Portanto precisamos criar uma alternativa para altera-la quando o usuário enviar uma imagem, isso pode ser feito com Javascript+HTML:

```
<?php
// if(isset($_SESSION['id']) && $_SESSION['id'] == $adminPagina){
// Isso é apenas um exemplo:
// Se estiver logado e o usuário conectado for administrador da respectiva página, exiba as funções:
?>
<form action="edit_logo-upd.php" method="post">

  <!-- A função desses "label" é para quando clicar acionar o "input" com o mesmo valor de "id" setado no "for" -->

  <label for="alterarLogo">
    <img src="https://goo.gl/Kmg0EB" width="20" height="20" class="alterar" alt="Alterar">
  </label>

  <label for="salvarLogo">
    <span class="salvar" id="salvar" style="display: none;"> Salvar </span> 
  </label>

  <!-- Estes inputs estão aqui, com display:none, para que não sejam mostrados -->
  <input name="logo" id="alterarLogo" style="display:none;" type="file">
  <input name="salvar" id="salvarLogo" style="display:none;" type="submit">

</form>
<?
// }
?>
```

> Javascript:

Para que possamos pegar a imagem enviada pelo usuário e exibirmos no local do logo antigo, é preciso acrescentar um Javascript:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("alterarLogo").addEventListener("change", function() {
// Isso irá "monitorar" se houver mudança no input/campo do logo

       document.getElementById('logo').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
       // Isso irá inserir a imagem enviada pelo usuário no lugar do logo antigo

       document.getElementById("salvar").style.display = "block";
       // Isso irá exibir o botão/texto de salvar.
});
</script>
```

Acredito que isso irá ser suficiente para uma previa/simulação real, assim como ocorre com o Facebook e Twitter, sem que usuário tenha que esperar para visualizar a foto/capa e pode salvar se gostar. :]

> Estou editando uma alternativa para o lado do servidor, usando SESSION, embora não considere ideal, estou apenas necessitando de informações de como a imagem está sendo salva (para utilizar mesmas variáveis).